# BX Slider - where has my border gone?

Tags: bxslider

I have BX Slider installed and integrated on the following page:
http://1080422389.n303457.test.prositehosting.co.uk/index.php

Each property box is contained with a class (.slide) which looks like this:

```
.slide {
font-family: "open-sans";
background-color: #fff; 
border: 1px solid #6F9258;
width: 400px;
height: 480px;
}
```

However when we have a page where there are fewer properties available:
http://1080422389.n303457.test.prositehosting.co.uk/Leswalt-property-for-sale.php

The 1px border on the far right box is missing?

Here's the custom js were using for the slider:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.slider').bxSlider({
slideWidth: 398,
minSlides: 2,
maxSlides: 12,
moveSlides: 2,
slideMargin: 10,
ticker: false,
speed: 1000,
nextSelector: '#slider-next',
prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
nextText: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Next 
&nbsp;&raquo;</button>',
prevText: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">&laquo;&nbsp; Previous</button>'
});
});
```

Hope someone can help. Thank you.
NJ

Answer (score 0):

The border is showing but it is just outside of the div box.

If you lower the margin-right of your ".slider" class you will see that the border is getting displayed.

So your problem is, that your outer container class ".bx-wrapper" is too small. It has a max width of 806px.

```html
<div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 806px; margin: 0px auto;">
```

If you set this to e.g. 810px your border will be fine.

Hope that helps you and you can figure out where this property gets set and change its value.

Comment: the max-width, in Firebug, is showing as being held in a class called element.style {margin: 0 auto;max-width: 806px;} which I can't see referenced in any of the CSS files. Is this being generated somewhere else?  I tried adding max-width: 810px; to the jquery.bxslider.css file but it's showing as striked through in Firebug.

Comment: I edited the custom.js file and increased the slideWidth to 400, which sets the width of bx-wrapper to max-width: 810px; however the border remains hidden?

Comment: i think it is generated via javascript in the getViewportMaxWidth() method but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: It's generated by the slideWidth value in the custom.js script but I've changed that and the max-width value is now 810px, as you'd advised, yet the border remains hidden. Has got me completely stumped.

Comment: if you use a higher value then 810 does this help? Maybe the box is still too small with 810